# Interpretation of Angular Momentum flux from stress energy tensor in Black hole superradiance

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, angular-momentum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, kerr-metric

While studying the superradiance of a scalar field in Kerr geometry, we show that the energy and angular momentum of the Kerr black hole are extracted by the superradiant modes. I understand the energy flux across the horizon part. But I do not understand the interpretation of the angular momentum flux of the scalar field across the horizon being negative implies the angular momentum of the black hole decreases. The angular momentum flux across the 2-surface $r=r_+$ with the normal pointing in the inward radial direction is given by
$$ \frac{dJ}{dt}= -\int T^r\hspace{0.2mm}_\phi(-g)^\frac{1}{2}d\theta d\phi=4\pi Mr_+m(\omega-\Omega_Hm)$$
We are working in ($+---$) metric convention. How do I understand that if $\frac{dJ}{dt}<0$ which is the case when $\omega<\Omega_Hm$, implies that the black hole's is losing it's angular momentum. The problem I am facing is that if $T^r\hspace{0.2mm}_\phi$ is that of the scalar field then $\frac{dJ}{dt}<0$ would imply that the angular momentum flux is outgoing from the horizon. This would mean that the scalar field angular momentum increases. But we know that in near horizon limit, a particle is forced to move with the angular velocity of the event horizon, which would means the scalar field should have the same angular momentum as that of the black hole. Hence outgoing angular momentum flux should increase the angular momentum of the scalar field which implies increase in angular momentum of the black hole, which obviously shouldn't be true.
Kindly help.